# How to count the number of set in the powerset?

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a list of integers, is there an algorithm to count the number of sets in the powerset? This shouldn't include the empty set, and, for example, `{1,2,3}` is the same as `{2,3,1}`, so they shouldn't be counted twice (i.e. powerset).

**Note: The elements of the list are not necessarily unique.**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

Comment: thanks I have never seen this abbreviated to poweset

Comment: A set has one power set. The number of elements in the power set is `2**len(s)`, where `s` is the starting set, or `2**len(set(l))` for a list that might contain duplicates. Excluding the empty set leaves `2**len(set(l)) - 1`.

Comment: How are you handling multiple entries that are the same? If your set is {1,2,2} what is the "power set" you are looking for?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the number of power sets or do you want to actually generate them all?

Comment: If the input is {1,2,2} then the output should be like 3 because of [ {1},{2},{1,2} ]. Note that there is two 2's, so I don't treat them as unique, so the number here is not 2^3=8...

Comment: I just want the number of them.

Comment: Wouldn't it be 2^(no. Of different numbers) - 1.

Comment: {1,2,2} is not a set, it is a list. The set of elements in the list {1,2,2} is {1,2}, so @SteveJessop's answer is correct.

Comment: Since you just want the number of sets, I'm inclined to think this is a [math.se] problem (well, it is if there exists a formula) (i.e. possibly not particularly appropriate for [so]).

Comment: @SteveJessop Presumably for `1,2,2,3`, we shouldn't count `1,2,3` twice, so it needs to be complicated a little more.

Comment: @Dukeling: it doesn't need to be complicated any more than what I've said. `len(set([1,2,2,3]))` is 3.

Comment: @Dukeling The OP's example using {1,2,2} does not include multiple occurrences. There is no `2,2` or `1,2,2` in the desired output. Nor is there an empty set, but that may be by design as well.

Comment: @Dukeling: you're not using the word "set" in any meaning that I recognise. `1,2,2,3` is not a set. Of course it's possible the questioner also isn't using the word in any meaning I recognise, which is exactly why I commented instead of answering :-) Since my comment, though, the questioner has said that the output for `[1,2,2]` should be 3, so I think they probably *do* mean to count sets.

Comment: @Dukeling I figured you had :)

Answer (score 2):

A set is defined as only containing unique/distinct elements. The number of sets in a set's powerset is `2^elements_in_set`. The powerset contains the empty set, so what you want is `2^elements_in_set - 1`.

So, the number of sets in the powerset of the set of a list is `2^unique_elements_in_list`, and the number without the empty set is `2^unique_elements_in_list - 1`.

---

Another way to think of it is to create a bit array which has the same size as the number of unique elements. Each bit in the array corresponds to whether that element is in that particular powerset element. Let's say your elements are 9, 7, 4. Here's what the mapping would look like:

```
powerset element | 9 | 7 | 4  
-----------------+---+---+---
[]               | 0 | 0 | 0 
[4]              | 0 | 0 | 1
[7]              | 0 | 1 | 0
[4, 7]           | 0 | 1 | 1 
[9]              | 1 | 0 | 0
[4, 9]           | 1 | 0 | 1
[7, 9]           | 1 | 1 | 0  
[4, 7, 9]        | 1 | 1 | 1
```

So you really just end up counting in binary. How many numbers can you make with `n` binary digits? `2^n`. How many excluding zero? `2^n - 1`.

---

To actually generate the powerset, here is some code. Note it uses lists for convenience.

```
def gen_powerset(l):
    if not l:
        yield []
        return
    for sub_powerset in gen_powerset(l[1:]):
        yield sub_powerset
        yield [l[0]] + sub_powerset
```

Example:

```
>>> list(gen_powerset(list(set([1, 4, 2, 2, 3]))))
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], 
 [4], [1, 4], [2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> len(list(gen_powerset(list(set([1, 4, 2, 2, 3])))))
16
```

Note that 16 is `2^4`, which is the number of unique elements in `[1, 4, 2, 2, 3]`.

Much easier to raise 2 to a power than generate the whole set just to count it, though!

Comment: 2^()-1 because empty set is to be excluded.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: why exclude the empty set? that is also part of the power set.

Comment: Op wants it that way. Its mentioned in the problem statement.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: oops reading comprehension fail, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools [combinations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function to generate every sub set of S without repetion.

```
def powerset(iterable):
    result = set()
    for l in xrange(1, len(iterable) + 1):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(iterable, l):
            result.add(subset)
    return sorted(result, key=len)

S = ['x', 'y' ,'z', 'y']
for subset in powerset(S):
    print subset
```

Result:

```
('z',)
('y',)
('x',)
('z', 'y')
('x', 'y')
('y', 'y')
('x', 'z')
('y', 'z')
('y', 'z', 'y')
('x', 'y', 'z')
('x', 'z', 'y')
('x', 'y', 'y')
('x', 'y', 'z', 'y')
```

Comment: This is printing out permutations (i.e. order matters). I want it without ordering.

Comment: just fixed it :) combinations is the right function.

Comment: But now I see 
('x', 'y', 'z')
('x', 'z', 'y')
this is both the same set....

Comment: It might seems like it's the same subset but it actually uses two different 'y'. You can't avoid this, unless you use a set. See my code

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

i = set([1, 2, 3])

for z in chain.from_iterable(combinations(i, r) for r in range(len(i)+1)):
    print z
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates play no role in the number of sets in the powerset - you can simply use the powerset formula - `2n-1` (as motivated below), where `n` is the number of unique elements.

The motivation - each unique element can either be picked, or not picked (it doesn't matter which occurrence we pick), so there are 2 possibilities for each unique element, thus `2*2*...*2 = 2n` possibilities in total. The `-1` is there to exclude the empty set.

**'Sets' with duplicates:**

A more interesting problem is generating the powerset if we assume each 'set' can contain duplicates (but not more occurrences than is in the input).

So, for something like `1,2,2,3`, some of the 'sets' that needs to be counted would be `2,2,3`, `1,2,2`, `2,2`, etc.

Let's think about this.

For `1,2,2,3`, we can either pick 1 or not pick it (2 possibilities), we can pick 0-2 two's (3 possibilities), we can pick 3 or not pick it (2 possibilities).

Note that there are `number of occurrences + 1` possibilities for each distinct element.

So, pseudo-code:

```
setCount = 1
for each distinct element e
   setCount *= 1 + number of occurrences of e
output setCount-1
```

Comment: OP wants the "number of sets in the powerset"; sets do not contain duplicates, so (1,2,2,3) shouldn't count.

Comment: @AaronDufour I still think this may be what OP is looking for - added a note to my answer so that, either way, I answer the question.